# JavaFX | changing Line anchor?

Tags: javafx

I tried drawing a line and changing its end coordinate when dragging.
The problem is, it changes both of the lines' ends, with respect to the middle, supposedly the anchor.

Is there a way to move the anchor to the start of the line?

My code is:

```
        Line path = new Line(30,30, 70 , 75);
        path.setStrokeWidth(5);

        Circle point = new Circle(3);
        point.setCenterX(path.getEndX());
        point.setCenterY(path.getEndY());
        point.setFill(Paint.valueOf("red"));

        point.setOnMouseDragged(e ->{

            point.setCenterX(e.getX());
            point.setCenterY(e.getY());

            path.setEndX(point.getCenterX());
            path.setEndY(point.getCenterY());

        });

        Group shapes = new Group();
        shapes.getChildren().addAll(path, point);
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(shapes);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());


        primaryStage.setScene(scene);



        primaryStage.show();
```

the result:

[image]
The ideal is that the pivot point will be at the start of the line, and not at the middle.

Comment: What layout (e.g. `StackPane`) did you put the `Line` in?

Comment: @Slaw borderBane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is not the line growing or shrinking in both directions; instead, what's happening is, as the line changes length, the `BorderPane` repositions it in order to keep it centered. The same thing is happening with the "rotation". When you move an end in such a way as to change the angle of the line, the bounding box changes in a way that, when the `BorderPane` repositions the line, causes the other end to move in the opposite direction.

More specifically, the `BorderPane` is repositioning the `Group`—effectively the same thing since `Group` doesn't position its children. One fix for this is to make the `Group` unmanaged. This will stop the `BorderPane` from repositioning the `Group` as its bounds change. Note, however, that this will also stop the `Group` from contributing to the size and layout calculations of the `BorderPane`.

Here's an example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static void installDragHandlers(Circle circle) {
        circle.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            Point2D offset = new Point2D(
                    event.getX() - circle.getCenterX(),
                    event.getY() - circle.getCenterY()
            );
            circle.setUserData(offset);
            event.consume();
        });
        circle.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            Point2D offset = (Point2D) circle.getUserData();
            circle.setCenterX(event.getX() - offset.getX());
            circle.setCenterY(event.getY() - offset.getY());
            event.consume();
        });
        circle.setOnMouseReleased(event -> {
            circle.setUserData(null);
            event.consume();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Line line = new Line(200, 200, 400, 200);
        line.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Circle start = new Circle(5, Color.GREEN);
        start.centerXProperty().bindBidirectional(line.startXProperty());
        start.centerYProperty().bindBidirectional(line.startYProperty());
        installDragHandlers(start);

        Circle end = new Circle(5, Color.RED);
        end.centerXProperty().bindBidirectional(line.endXProperty());
        end.centerYProperty().bindBidirectional(line.endYProperty());
        installDragHandlers(end);

        Group group = new Group(line, start, end);
        group.setManaged(false);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(group), 600, 400));
        primaryStage.setTitle("SO-55196882");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

The `Line` is initialized with hard coded start and end points so that it is initially centered in the scene (whose initial dimensions are also hard coded).

Answer (score 0):

Put shapes in group.

```
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws AWTException {
    final Line path = new Line(30, 30, 70, 75);
    path.setStrokeWidth(5);

    final Circle point = new Circle(3);
    point.setCenterX(path.getEndX());
    point.setCenterY(path.getEndY());
    point.setFill(Paint.valueOf("red"));

    point.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {

        point.setCenterX(e.getX());
        point.setCenterY(e.getY());

        path.setEndX(point.getCenterX());
        path.setEndY(point.getCenterY());

    });

    final Group root = new Group(path, point);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```